# Why subprocess of a script disappears after signal is sent?

Tags: unix, posix, kill

I have a script (flexblocks) that prints a status of my system every second.
So that I can pipe it into lemonbar. It looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

main() {
  while true; do
    sleep "1s" // This

    // ...

    printf '%s\n' "some status here"
  done
}

refresh() {
  unset "$@"
}

trap "refresh node" "USR1"
trap "refresh pmix song" "USR2"
main
```

As you can see, I trapped two custom user signals before the *main* function is
invoked. These are called from other scripts to refresh the bar. So in the
*refresh* function I unset the given variables to load them again and I also
want to kill the sleep process mentioned as `// This` in the code above.

However, the *sleep* process suddenly disappears when the signal is sent. Any
ideas?

---

This is the output of `pstree "$(pidof -x flexblocks)"` when I run it outside
of the script:

```
flexblocks───sleep
```

And it is the output of the same commnad within the function of signal USR
signals:

```
flexblocks---pstree
```

`pgrep` does not find any process named *sleep* when running inside the refresh function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trapped shell signals are not delivered until after foreground commands — a command the shell is waiting to exit before it advances to its next instruction – are completed.  (The `wait` builtin is an exception to this.) ([POSIX.1-2008 Shell and Utilities §2.11](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11))  Thus, your *sleep* has exited by the time the USR1 or USR2 trap is sprung.

For example:

```
$ cat zzz.sh
#! /bin/sh

trap 'echo USR1 $(date)' USR1

date
sleep 15
date

$ sh zzz.sh &
[1] 7689
Thu Feb  3 11:52:18 CST 2022

$ kill -USR1 7689

$
USR1 Thu Feb 3 11:52:33 CST 2022
Thu Feb  3 11:52:33 CST 2022

[1]+  Done                    sh zzz.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! Replacing `sleep 1` with `sleep 1 & wait $!` worked perfectly fine 